# MS Access: How can I put the groupings with the largest date on top?

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, report, ms-access-2013

I have a report. Currently, I am grouping by `FG`, then sorting by `Job Date` DESC, and finally sorting by `Line` (not shown in image) ASCEND. However, if you look at the image, you'll notice that the first grouping has `Job Date`'s `7/25/2016` and `7/18/2016`. I think it would look better if I somehow get the groupings with `8/1/2016` at the top of the report. How can I do this?

[image: 1 - medGxLD.png]

So to visualize the end goal, imagine that groupings 2 and 3 are at the top of the report followed by grouping 1 and finally grouping 4.

**Update:** Added SQL of the query that feeds the report.

```
SELECT 

    dbo_jobmatl.item, 
    dbo_jobmatl.description, 
    dbo_job.job_date, 
    dbo_job.item AS FGNumber, 
    dbo_job.job, 
    dbo_job.suffix, 
    [qty_complete]*[matl_qty] AS qty_req, 
    dbo_jobmatl.qty_issued, 
    [qty_issued]-[qty_req] AS Variance, 
    IIf([qty_req]=0,0,[variance]/[qty_req]) AS Overage, 
    dbo_jobmatl.scrap_fact, 
    dbo_job.whse, 
    dbo_job.Uf_Production_Line, 
    dbo_job.stat, 
    Switch([Uf_Job_Verified]=1,"Yes",[Uf_Job_Verified]=0,"No") AS verified

FROM 

    dbo_jobmatl 
    INNER JOIN dbo_job ON (dbo_jobmatl.job = dbo_job.job) AND (dbo_jobmatl.suffix = dbo_job.suffix)

WHERE 

        (((dbo_jobmatl.item)=[Forms]![MainForm]![Text0]) 
    AND ((dbo_job.job_date) Between [Forms]![MainForm]![Text2] And [Forms]![MainForm]![Text4]))

ORDER BY 

    dbo_job.job_date DESC, 
    dbo_job.item DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

if the first query(your_query) has fg , job_date

create a second query based on the first

```
select job_date , fg
from your_query
order by
job_date desc, fg
```

use this query as a source for your report

You can inside your report assign line number sequentially

**Edit:**
When i review the query, it seem you make grouping on FG within the report,   so it's sorted by fg.

To get the groupings with 8/1/2016 at the top of the report , you can compute RANK for every group, and group inside the report by RANK.

Add calculated expression in the query as:

```
rank: (SELECT COUNT(T1.fg)
    FROM
    dbo_job AS T1
      WHERE T1.fg < table3.fg)+1
```

The result of that query for sample data:

```
 fg         job_date    rank
 12160340   7/25/2016   1
 12160340   7/18/2016   1
 12195704   1/8/2016    3
 12195704   7/25/2016   3
 12280435   1/8/2016    5
```

as you see , the highest rank 5 , for fg=12280435   with date 1/8/20016
the next  is rank 3

Comment: Why do I need a 2nd query? Can't I just implement the sorting in the 1st query?

Comment: Can you write the sql of the first query you use in the report.

Comment: As i review the sql, you make grouping on FG within report not group by in sql, so it's sorted by fg. If you want to order by job_date you should create the grouping in the sql. Are you in need to all these columns?